# What does the fail keyword do in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I am learning Ruby and encountered the `fail` keyword. What does it mean?

```
if password.length < 8
   fail "Password too short"
end
unless  username
   fail "No user name set"
end
```

Comment: In addition to the below answers its worth knowing that people use `raise` when handling exceptions and `fail` when not.

Comment: It's not a keyword, it's a method.

Comment: Documentation: [Kernel#fail](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Kernel.html#method-i-fail)

Comment: Also note, you can write these as single line statements: `fail "Password too short" if password.length < 8` and `fail "No user name set" unless  username`

Answer (score 145, accepted):

In Ruby, `fail` is synonymous with `raise`. The `fail` keyword is a method of the `Kernel` module which is included by the class `Object`. The `fail` method raises a runtime error just like the `raise` keyword.

The `fail` method has three overloads:

- `fail`: raises a `RuntimeError` without an error message.
- `fail(string)`: raises a `RuntimeError` with the string argument as an error message:

  ```
  fail "Failed to open file"
  ```
- `fail(exception [, string [, array]])`: raises an exception of class `exception` (first argument) with an optional error message (second argument) and callback information (third argument).

  Example: Assume you define a function which should fail if given a bad argument. It is better to raise an `ArgumentError` and not a `RuntimeError`:

  ```
  fail ArgumentError, "Illegal String"
  ```

  Another Example: You can pass the whole [backtrace](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Thread/Backtrace/Location.html) to the `fail` method so you can access the trace inside the `rescue` block:

  ```
  fail ArgumentError, "Illegal String", caller
  ```

  [`caller`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Kernel.html#method-i-caller) is a Kernel method which returns the backtrace as an array of strings in the form `file:line: in 'method'`.

> With no arguments, raises the exception in $! or raises a RuntimeError
>   if $! is nil. With a single String argument, raises a RuntimeError
>   with the string as a message. Otherwise, the first parameter should be
>   the name of an Exception class (or an object that returns an Exception
>   object when sent an exception message). The optional second parameter
>   sets the message associated with the exception, and the third
>   parameter is an array of callback information. Exceptions are caught
>   by the rescue clause of begin...end blocks.

Source: [Ruby Documentation on the Kernel Module](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Kernel.html).

Comment: Can you give 3 simple examples with the 3 bullet points? It will make your answer more concrete.. :)

Comment: Wow, +1, crazybob's better than Ruby docs http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Kernel.html#method-i-raise :-)))

Comment: It worked for me but Rubocop converted it to `raise`

Answer (score 33):

[Rubocop](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rubocop/RuboCop/Cop/Style/SignalException) says about usage of both words;

> 'Use `fail` instead of `raise` to signal exceptions.'
>
> 'Use `raise` instead of `fail` to rethrow exceptions.'

Here is an example.

```
def sample
  fail 'something wrong' unless success?
rescue => e
  logger.error e
  raise
end
```

Comment: +1 for style advisory; even if they are identical semantically using each in their intended setting helps convey intention better

Comment: Unfortunately, the link is not working any more.

Comment: https://github.com/rubocop/ruby-style-guide#raise-vs-fail

They seem to have updated the guideline. At the time of writing: 

**Prefer raise over fail for exceptions.**

Answer (score 26):

`fail` == `raise`

In other words, `fail` is just a popular alias for `raise` error-raising method. Usage:

```
fail ArgumentError, "Don't argue with me!"
```

Answer (score 7):

[www.ruby-doc.org](http://www.ruby-doc.org) is your friend.  When I googled `rubydoc fail` "[Kernel](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Kernel.html#method-i-fail)" was the first hit.  My advice is, when in doubt, go to the definitive source for definitional stuff like this.

Comment: Woot, that really is a FAIL. Code example for fail is copy-paste from raise o_O

Comment: @VajkHermecz fail is an alias of raise, so it reuses the documentation. Compare with the docs for Array#map and Array#collect