# Need 'return' statement following 'fail' call in a Ruby method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, error-handling, return

I got the following code from a Rails tutorial:

```
def do_something
    # some code here....

    if @user.blank?
        fail NotAuthenticatedError
        return
    end

    # more code here...
end
```

Is the `return` statement necessary, or is the `fail` call sufficient to stop the rest of the code in this method from running? Perhaps it depends on how the `NotAuthenticatedError` is handled?

Comment: fail is similar to raise. so it wont pass that. see this 
http://apidock.com/ruby/Kernel/fail

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you don't need the return.

```
def do_something
    puts "start"
    fail NotAuthenticatedError
    puts "this doesn't print"
end
```

That code will never get to the last line.

Check out:

[what-does-the-fail-keyword-do-in-ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18811675/what-does-the-fail-keyword-do-in-ruby)